# Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: setMaxRows() out of range. 2147483647 > 50000000

Tags: mysql, oracle-adf, oracle12c

I am using Oracle jDeveloper 12c. When I try to export the table to the Excel, I am getting the exception. This was working fine earlier.

Here is the stack trace.

```
oracle.jbo.SQLStmtException: JBO-29114 ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is JBO-27122. Error message parameters are {0=select * from wd.portfolio_master}
    at oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.buildResultSet(QueryCollection.java:1432)
    at oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.executeQuery(QueryCollection.java:976)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.executeQueryForCollection(ViewObjectImpl.java:7849)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.execute(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1398)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQueryForMasters(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1665)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQueryForMode(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1549)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQuery(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1529)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getFinderRS(ViewObjectImpl.java:18591)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getAllRowsIterator(ViewObjectImpl.java:18025)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.getAllChildrenNodesIterator(JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.java:937)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierNodeBinding$IterateOnlyArrayList.iterator(JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.java:815)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.OptimizedRowDataManager.setRowIndex(OptimizedRowDataManager.java:58)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierBinding$FacesModel.setRowIndex(FacesCtrlHierBinding.java:921)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.setRowIndex(UIXCollection.java:572)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXTable.setRowIndex(UIXTable.java:782)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector._renderAllDataRows(CollectionExportDirector.java:512)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector._renderDataRows(CollectionExportDirector.java:447)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector._renderContent(CollectionExportDirector.java:127)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector.export(CollectionExportDirector.java:109)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.ExportCollectionActionListener.processAction(ExportCollectionActionListener.java:199)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcast(UIXComponentBase.java:1113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:179)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.nav.RichCommandMenuItem.broadcast(RichCommandMenuItem.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:124)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:124)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
**Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: setMaxRows() out of range. 2147483647 > 50000000.**
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1058)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:972)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:903)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.setMaxRows(StatementImpl.java:2758)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_com_mysql_jdbc_JDBC4PreparedStatement.setMaxRows(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.buildResultSet(QueryCollection.java:1346)
    at oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.executeQuery(QueryCollection.java:976)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.executeQueryForCollection(ViewObjectImpl.java:7849)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.execute(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1398)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQueryForMasters(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1665)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQueryForMode(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1549)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQuery(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1529)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getFinderRS(ViewObjectImpl.java:18591)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getAllRowsIterator(ViewObjectImpl.java:18025)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.getAllChildrenNodesIterator(JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.java:937)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierNodeBinding$IterateOnlyArrayList.iterator(JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.java:815)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.OptimizedRowDataManager.setRowIndex(OptimizedRowDataManager.java:58)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierBinding$FacesModel.setRowIndex(FacesCtrlHierBinding.java:921)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.setRowIndex(UIXCollection.java:572)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXTable.setRowIndex(UIXTable.java:782)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector._renderAllDataRows(CollectionExportDirector.java:512)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector._renderDataRows(CollectionExportDirector.java:447)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector._renderContent(CollectionExportDirector.java:127)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.CollectionExportDirector.export(CollectionExportDirector.java:109)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.export.ExportCollectionActionListener.processAction(ExportCollectionActionListener.java:199)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcast(UIXComponentBase.java:1113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:179)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.nav.RichCommandMenuItem.broadcast(RichCommandMenuItem.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:124)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:124)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Comment: FWIW: 2147483647 is the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer (in 2's complement). I'm fairly certain it is not a random coincidence; and whatever is setting it (or letting a default 'max integer value' remain) should kindly limit the value to 50000000.

Comment: Can you please explain me in brief

Comment: I have checked all the columns int the database which is having int datatype but no where i have that much of high value which crosses the limit i.e.50000000

Comment: How many rows are found with a select count over the table?

Comment: Hi.. I got the Solution. In ViewPageDef.xml file there is a RangeSize which was set to 25 by default.
i.e.
<iterator Binds="PortfolioStakeHoldersVO1" RangeSize="25" DataControl="PortfoliosAppModuleDataControl"
              id="PortfolioStakeHoldersVO1Iterator"/>
I changed it to
<iterator Binds="PortfolioStakeHoldersVO1" RangeSize="200" DataControl="PortfoliosAppModuleDataControl"
              id="PortfolioStakeHoldersVO1Iterator"/>
 
Its working fine.
Thanks a lot for your Support .

Comment: @VidyaHugar does that work because 25 < 26 < 200? I am finding the same error when performing a data export in ADF. I don't want to only get back 200 rows though, so I am thinking I will need to set it to a much larger number, but I can't set my VOs to that large a number I think without performance issues on the pages when I am not exporting the data.